# Error on trying to authenticate against Bitstamp API using VBA HTTP Post

Tags: excel, vba, http, post

I'm trying to authenticate against Bitstamp's API as the first step in some automation that I want to run.  I've done this in VBA as I want to use a lot of excel's capability as the framework for the calls I want to make.  As far as I can see the signature sent is in the correct format, has the correct API Keys etc.

I've had to code a few other function (or rather got chatGPT to) as they don't come native to VBA I understand.  I'm a bit of a newbie with calling APIs so this could be wrong, but the results out of them seem to be matching my expectations.  Can anyone see where I've gone wrong please?  TIA

```
Sub ExecuteBitstampRequest()
    ' Set your Bitstamp API credentials
    Dim apiKey As String
    Dim apiKeySecret As String
    apiKey = "MyApiKey"
    apiKeySecret = "MySecretKey"
    
    ' Set other parameters
    Dim timestamp As String
    Dim nonce As String
    Dim content_type As String
    Dim payload As String
    Dim payload_string As String
    Dim message As String
    Dim signature As String
    Dim headers As Object
    Dim r As Object
    
    timestamp = CStr(Round((Now - #1/1/1970#) * 86400000, 0))
    nonce = GenerateUUID()
    content_type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    payload_string = "offset=1"
    
    ' Construct the message
    message = "BITSTAMP " & apiKey & _
              "POST" & _
              "www.bitstamp.net" & _
              "/api/v2/user_transactions/" & _
              "" & _
              content_type & _
              nonce & _
              timestamp & _
              "v2" & _
              payload_string
    
    Debug.Print message
    
    message = UTF8Bytes(message)
    
    ' Calculate HMAC-SHA256 signature
    signature = HMACSHA256(apiKeySecret, message)
    
    ' Create headers
    Set headers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    headers("X-Auth") = "BITSTAMP " & apiKey
    headers("X-Auth-Signature") = signature
    headers("X-Auth-Nonce") = nonce
    headers("X-Auth-Timestamp") = timestamp
    headers("X-Auth-Version") = "v2"
    headers("Content-Type") = content_type
    
    ' Make the HTTP request
    Set r = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    r.Open "POST", "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/user_transactions/", False
    For Each Header In headers.Keys
        r.setRequestHeader Header, headers(Header)
    Next Header
    r.send payload_string
    
    ' Check the response
    If r.Status <> 200 Then
        Debug.Print r.Status & " : " & r.responseText
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Verify the server signature
    Dim stringToSign As String
    stringToSign = nonce & timestamp & r.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")
    
    If Not VerifySignature(apiKeySecret, stringToSign, r.getResponseHeader("X-Server-Auth-Signature")) Then
        MsgBox "Signatures do not match"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Print the content
    MsgBox r.responseText
End Sub

Function GenerateUUID() As String
    Dim byteArray(15) As Byte
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Use the Rnd function to generate random bytes
    For i = 0 To 15
        byteArray(i) = Int((255 * Rnd) + 1)
    Next i

    ' Set the version bits to 4 (randomly generated UUID)
    byteArray(6) = (byteArray(6) And &HF) Or &H40

    ' Set the variant bits to 2 (RFC 4122)
    byteArray(8) = (byteArray(8) And &H3F) Or &H80

    ' Format the bytes as a string in UUID format
    GenerateUUID = _
        Right("00" & Hex(byteArray(0)), 2) & _
        Right("00" & Hex(byteArray(1)), 2) & _
        Right("00" & Hex(byteArray(2)), 2) & _
        Right("00" & Hex(byteArray(3)), 2) & "-" & _
        Right("00" & Hex(byteArray(4)), 2) & _
        Right("00" & Hex(byteArray(5)), 2) & "-" & _
        Right("00" & Hex(byteArray(6)), 2) & _
        Right("00" & Hex(byteArray(7)), 2) & "-" & _
        Right("00" & Hex(byteArray(8)), 2) & _
        Right("00" & Hex(byteArray(9)), 2) & "-" & _
        Right("00" & Hex(byteArray(10)), 2) & _
        Right("00" & Hex(byteArray(11)), 2) & _
        Right("00" & Hex(byteArray(12)), 2) & _
        Right("00" & Hex(byteArray(13)), 2) & _
        Right("00" & Hex(byteArray(14)), 2) & _
        Right("00" & Hex(byteArray(15)), 2)
    GenerateUUID = LCase(GenerateUUID)
    Debug.Print GenerateUUID
End Function



Function EncodeUrlParameters(parameters As String) As String
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    Dim i As Integer

    ReDim bytes(0 To Len(parameters) * 3) ' Allocate enough space

    ' Convert each character to UTF-8
    For i = 1 To Len(parameters)
        Dim charCode As Integer
        charCode = AscW(Mid(parameters, i, 1))

        If charCode < &H80 Then
            bytes(i - 1) = charCode And &H7F
        ElseIf charCode < &H800 Then
            bytes(i - 1) = &HC0 Or ((charCode \ &H40) And &H1F)
            bytes(i) = &H80 Or (charCode And &H3F)
        Else
            bytes(i - 1) = &HE0 Or ((charCode \ &H1000) And &HF)
            bytes(i) = &H80 Or ((charCode \ &H40) And &H3F)
            bytes(i + 1) = &H80 Or (charCode And &H3F)
        End If
    Next i

    ' Trim the byte array to the actual size
    ReDim Preserve bytes(0 To i - 1)

    ' Convert the byte array to a hex string
    EncodeUrlParameters = ""
    For i = LBound(bytes) To UBound(bytes)
        EncodeUrlParameters = EncodeUrlParameters & Right("0" & Hex(bytes(i)), 2)
    Next i
End Function


Function UTF8Bytes(text As String) As Byte()
    ' Function to convert text to UTF-8 encoded byte array
    Dim encoder As Object
    Set encoder = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    UTF8Bytes = encoder.GetBytes_4(text)
End Function

Function HMACSHA256(key As String, message As String) As String
    Dim hmac As Object
    Set hmac = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256")
    hmac.key = UTF8Bytes(key)
    
    Dim hashBytes() As Byte
    hashBytes = hmac.ComputeHash_2(UTF8Bytes(message))
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim result As String
    For i = LBound(hashBytes) To UBound(hashBytes)
        result = result & Right("0" & Hex(hashBytes(i)), 2)
    Next i
    
    HMACSHA256 = result
End Function


Function VerifySignature(key As String, message As String, signature As String) As Boolean
    ' Function to verify the HMAC-SHA256 signature
    VerifySignature = (HMACSHA256(key, message) = signature)
End Function
```

On running the main function, I still get the response back and the response code 403

`{"status": "error", "reason": "Invalid signature", "code": "API0005"}`

Comment: to help anyone else; I've finally figured this out.  The line 
message = UTF8Bytes(message)
just needed to be remove, as the hmacsha256 function didn't need it